# Aurelia Validation error messages DisplayName is not shown up

Tags: display, message, aurelia

I have a **Translation.json** file with application related properties defined.

```
{
"firstName": "Vorname",
"First Name": "Vorname",
"lastName": "Nachname",
"Last Name": "Nachname",
"Experience": "Erfahrung",
"experience": "erfahrung",
"Country": "Land",
"Currency": "Währung",
"currency": "währung",
"country": "land",
"DefaultSelectValue": "--${$displayName} auswählen--",
"switchLanguage": "Sprache wechseln",
"youHaveErrors": "Es gibt Fehler!",
"allGood": "Alles in Ordnung!",
"latestValidationResult": "Aktuelles Validierungsergebnis",
"heading": "Validierungsergebnis" }
```

Similarly I have validation messages placed in **Validation.json** file

```
{
"errorMessages": {
    "required": "${$displayName} fehlt!",
    "minLength": "Der ${$displayName} sollte mindestens ${$config.length} Zeichen lang sein",
    "matches": "${$displayName} ist nicht gültig",
    "email": "${$displayName} is not a valid email.",
 } }
```

and **Default Name space is Translation.json**, Now when i run the application the validation message doesn't  show up the displayName.

**HTML:**

```
 <span class="help-block" repeat.for="errorInfo of ValueErrors">${errorInfo.error.message & t:{ns:'validation'}}</span>
```

TypesScript:

```
ValidationRules.ensure('value').displayName(this.i18n.tr(model.displayName, {ns:'translation'})).required()
                .minLength(model.minLength)
                .on(this.model);
```

Output:
**${$displayName} fehlt!**

Expected:
 **Vorname fehlt!**

Is that the errorMessages should be declared in default Namespace or am I missing anything?

Comment: Could you maybe upload a sample showing the issue? Its hard to figure things out with regards to config without seing a real example

Comment: Thanks,
Anyhow the issue is resolved., It started working as expected after overriding the "getMessage" function to look for custom json file for error messages.

Comment: Could you post your solution so others with the same issue know what to do? Thx

Comment: @zewa666 
All that I have done is explicitly specifying to look the validation.json file for error messages,     `ValidationMessageProvider.prototype.getMessage = function (key) {
    const i18n = aurelia.container.get(I18N);
    const translation = i18n.tr(`errorMessages.${key}`, {ns:'validation'});
    return this.parser.parse(translation);
  };`

Comment: please add this as an answer and accept is as the answer

Answer (score -1):

ValidationMessageProvider.prototype.getMessage = function (key) { const i18n = aurelia.container.get(I18N);
const translation = i18n.tr(errorMessages.${key}, {ns:'validation'}); return this.parser.parse(translation);
};

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).